# Max absolute sum in a array

Tags: java, algorithm

I am came across this question recently but didn't get any idea about solving this. Can you some one help with pseudo code.

> Given an array with four integers A, B, C, D, shuffle them in some order. If the integers are unique then there are 24 shuffles. My task is get the best shuffle such that
>
> ```
> F(S) = abs(s[0]-s[1]) + abs(s[1]-s[2])+ abs(s[2]-s[3])
> ```
>
> is maximum

For example consider this example

```
A=5, B= 3, C=-1, D =5
s[0]=5, s[1]=-1, s[2]= 5, s[3] =3
```

will give me maximum sum which is

```
F[s] =14
```

The time and space complexity are O(1).

Comment: I tried your example and it gives me 14, not 15...

Comment: @templatetypedef you should undelete your answer.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I am unsure about the approach, because of time and space complexity O(1). Also I only want pseudo code, I dont want the solution, I am asking the suggestions for approach. Thanks for the reply though

Comment: Well, in this site you should show your effort instead of posting your problem and taking a cup of coffee while people here break their heads trying to solve your problem.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza The only solution I got is finding all the permutations, and appying the given formula. I am only asking approach, I never asked for any ready code and I hope you know the meaning of approach or pseudo code.

Comment: @user3096840 again, we know what does mean asking for an approach or an algorithm. But you need to show **what have you tried first**, otherwise people may think you're a lazy zombie that loves to leech from the effort of other people around the world. To avoid this, just show what have you tried, even if is as simple as a brute force approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your array has a bounded size, *any* algorithm you use that terminates will have time and space complexity O(1). Therefore, the simple algorithm of "try all permutations and find the best one" will solve the problem in the appropriate time bounds. I don't mean to say that this is by any stretch of the imagination the *ideal* algorithm, but if all you need is something that works in time/space O(1), then you've got your answer.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I thought if I try all permutations, the time complexity is n!. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @user3096840 In your question it seems like n is a constant, so it makes no sense to talk about asymptotic growth with regard to n, since *n does not grow* :)

Comment: Number of elements.. For example in the above case I have to check 24 combinations if all numbers are unique. I am not sure whether I am thinking correct or not

Comment: By the @templatetypedef, technically not any algorithm will be O(1), it could depend on unbounded aspects of the input like *A*

Comment: @user3096840 Yes. But n (the array size) is not a variable if your input array always has size 4. It would be a different story if your algorithm would need to work for arbitrary-sized arrays

Comment: @NiklasB I got it. Thanks for the explanation. That will help:)

Comment: @user3096840 Or in other words, yes the naive algorithm is O(n!), but n is constant and Big-Oh ignores constants, so O(n!) = O(1) in this case

Answer (score 4):

### Algorithm

Consider laying out your points in sorted order:

```
A  B  C  D
```

Let x be the distance AB

Let y be the distance BC

Let z be the distance CD

An order which will always give the best score is BDAC with score 2x+3y+2z.

### Example

In your example, the sorted points are:

```
A=-1 B= 3 C=5 D=5
x=4, y=2, z=0
```

So the best order will be BDAC=3->5->-1->5 with score 14.

### Hints towards Proof

You can prove this result be simply considering all permutations of the path between the 4 points, and computing the score in terms of x,y,z.

e.g.

```
ABCD -> x+y+z
ACBD -> x+3y+z
ADBC -> x+3y+2z
```

etc.

In any permutation, the score will use x at most twice (because A is on the end so the route can only go to or from A twice).  Similarly, z is used at most twice because D is on the end.  y can be used at most three times because there are three things being added.

The permutation BDAC uses x twice, z twice, and y three times so can never be beaten.

Comment: Thank you, I will try in the fashion you mentioned

Comment: @user3096840 My initial answer was flawed, hopefully the updated version makes more sense now!

Answer (score 2):

If array is sorted this solution also works:

```
F(S)= 2*abs(s[0]-s[3]) + abs(s[1]-s[2])
```

where **s[0]=A**, **s[1]=B**, **s[2]=C** and **s[3]=D**.

Comment: Good find, but the condition is it should satisfy that formula,I found the solution though, getting all the permutations of the numbers and applying the given formula and that worked.